# How to extend unavailable Locale.Language by default in action controller?

Tags: java, locale, struts, struts-1

So I am trying to implement a Struts 1 I18N application with some languages that are not supported by default (Swedish, Portuguese, Spanish etc.) But when I define `Locale.Portuguese` in action controller for example, it would shows me `PORTUGUESE cannot be resolved or is not a field`. Why? How can I extends it so that I can proceed with it? Can someone explains it how is it relatable?

```
public ActionForward french(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE", Locale.FRENCH);
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is this a new application? If so why are you using a framework that's been dead for about 10 years?

Comment: @Thomas Ikr. But I have to. Because there is an application based on Struts 1 was implemented & used for many years (and still) by my company. I am instructed to implement I18N for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't find locale for your country and language in `java.util.Locale` as static constants, you can create them yourself like this,

```
Locale portugese = new Locale("pt","PT");
Locale swedish = new Locale("sv","SE");
Locale spanish = new Locale("es","ES");
```

There are variations based upon the country where the same language is spoken but above should be good.

[This locale information may be helpful for you](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html)

Comment: I created a locale object with constructor in the class with the way you've provided but `Locale.PORTUGUESE` still can't be resolved?

Comment: You can't use `Locale.PORTUGUESE` as Locale class does not have any static variable `PORTUGUESE` declared which is why you are getting the error message. You need to replace `Locale.PORTUGUESE` with this `new Locale("pt","PT")` or declare this as static variable in your class and use or use it in this statement like this `session.setAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE", new Locale("pt","PT"));`

Comment: Console shows `WARNING:   Resource org/apache/struts/actions/LocalStrings_en.properties Not Found.` and `SEVERE: Action[/changeLocale] missing resource in key method map 'pt'` as I defined the method for `/changeLocale` action as 'pt' in properties file.

Comment: You may need to do additional configuration for the new locale (provide the resource file that contains Portuguese text for localization) you are trying to use. Its been over a decade since I last used struts, so I may not be exactly able to pin point and tell you how you could fix the problem. Try googling with the error and you should get some pointers for resolving your problem. But most likely my guess is you need to supply resource like just like `LocalStrings_en.properties` and for Portuguese it should be `LocalStrings_pt.properties`

Comment: Okay so I found out the issue that caused the error. It was my careless mistake and not related with this. Anyway your answer did helped me out how to create `Locate` manually. Sincerely appreciate your assistance over here ;-)

Comment: Pleased to helped you :)